# Using a WCF return argument of type ObservableCollection<CustomType> in a xaml defined datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wcf

Can't seem to figure this out and I thought It would be easy.

I have a WCF service that returns an observablecollection

I want to call the wcf service from code behind and place the results into a observablecollection _myObser. I need this _myObser accessible from my XAML..

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ComboBox x:Name="cbGroup" SelectedItem="{Binding Group, Mode=TwoWay}"
      ItemsSource="??" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

I guess my first question is there a better way to do this?

My second question am I able to do something like this? I seem to always get errors

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
<observablecollection<customtype> x:name""....
```

I also tried to use my wcfservicereference return arguments as a resource but I get this error.

```
xmlns:STA="clr-namespace:ePagesSilverlightWebsite.ePagesWCFServiceReference"

<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <STA:getAccessLevelsCompletedEventArgs x:Name="_myOb" />
 </navigation:Page.Resources>
```

is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataContext of the page to either the code behind (this) or a view model, define the Observable collection as a readonly public property in the code behind or the view model and bind to the property.

Comment: I am not experienced enough to interpret this well... If I set it to read only how will I change the data when I get my results from my WCF calls...

Comment: readonly means you won't replace the *collection* not you won;t replace the *contents* of the collection. ObservableCollection is powerful because it notifies the binding about changes to the contents (items added and removed)